# Appache Proxy pass to nodejs

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy, webserver

I have Apache proxy pass to serve the nodejs files running on the server.

httpd.conf

```
ProxyPass /datacollect1 http://localhost:5000/datacollect1 
ProxyPass /datacollect2 http://localhost:5000/datacollect2 
ProxyPass /datacollect3 http://localhost:5000/datacollect3
```

This method works fine, but its not the best of solutions when adding more and more proxies. Is there any easier way than adding one by one??

Thank you so much